# In Active Directory, how do I find all groups I'm the secretary for?

Tags: c#, active-directory

We use the `secretary` property of Active Directory, which is a multivalued DN property.  I want to efficiently find all the groups for which a given user is a listed `secretary`.  What is the best way to perform this query in C#/.NET?

Comment: do a google search on how to access groups using active directory or using `PrincipalContext` please show more effort.. as well as show what you have tried thus far..

Comment: I did lots of google searches, and since I didn't find it in a relatively canned/straightforward way I posted it here.  Eventually I'll figure it out and answer my own q for posterity, unless someone writes it first.  Don't think the downvotes are warranted.

Comment: Also, I believe there is a _lot_ of bad info out there about efficient ways to query Active Directory when you have to do some of the less-than-common searches, and so was of the opinion that this question would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will return a list of sAMAccountNames of groups in `context`'s OU that include `distinguishedName` as one of the secretaries listed:

```
var filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(secretary=" + distinguishedName + "))";

PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(...); // place to search from
var up = new GroupPrincipal(context);
var list = new List<string>();
using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(up))
{
    var ds = searcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher() as DirectorySearcher;

    // if you only want to search in a single OU (as defined by 'context')
    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel; 
    ds.Filter = filter;
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");

    var results = ds.FindAll();
    foreach (SearchResult r in results)
    {
        var name = r.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value as string;
        list.Add(name);
    }
}
```